# scala - sum up map's value by position

Tags: scala

I have a map like this

```
var kk:scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Array[Int]] = Map(2 -> Array(1, 3), 1 -> Array(2, 8), 3 -> Array(4, 5))
```

What I need is sum up value arrays by position, like numpy array adding, and the result should be like this Array(1+2+4, 3+8+5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or a little shorter using `.values` to just get a `List` of the arrays, and `.transpose` to apply `.map` on each "column":

```
scala> val data = Map(2 -> Array(1, 3), 1 -> Array(2, 8), 3 -> Array(4, 5))
data: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Array[Int]] = Map(2 -> Array(1, 3), 1 -> Array(2, 8), 3 -> Array(4, 5))

scala> data.values.transpose.map(_.sum)
res4: Iterable[Int] = List(7, 16)
```

And add `.toArray` if you'd like to get an `Array`:

```
scala> data.values.transpose.map(_.sum).toArray
res5: Array[Int] = Array(7, 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to `iterate` over the map to get the separate list of first and second elements of your map values. Then apply `fold` function.

```
scala> val data = Map(2 -> Array(1, 3), 1 -> Array(2, 8), 3 -> Array(4, 5))
data: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Array[Int]] = Map(2 -> Array(1, 3), 1 -> Array(2, 8), 3 -> Array(4, 5))

scala> data.map(kv => kv._2.head -> kv._2.last).foldLeft(0, 0)((a, b) => (a._1 + b._1) -> (a._2 + b._2))
res11: (Int, Int) = (7,16)
```

if you want the result to be explicitly an `Array` do `.productIterator.toArray` on above result.

```
scala> data.map(kv => kv._2.head -> kv._2.last).foldLeft(0, 0)((a, b) => (a._1 + b._1) -> (a._2 + b._2)).productIterator.toArray
res13: Array[Any] = Array(7, 16)
```